# Plotly dash populate dcc.Dropdown options from api call response

Tags: python, callback, dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm trying to implement a callback to populate the options of a plotly dash dcc.Dropdown with data i get back from an external api call. My current code looks like this, but the options just don't populate and I'm not sure why. note that this is part of a larger application.

I am able to log the options, showing the logged options block executes, but they do not display in the ui for some reason.

```py
# metadata.py

from dash import html, dcc

def generate_header(metadata_index):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H3(
                id={"type": "project-metadata", "index": metadata_index},
                style={"textAlign": "center"},
            ),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                [], '',
                id="wave-select",
                style={"margin":"25px"},
                placeholder="Select a wave"
        
            )
        ]
    )
```

```py
# metadata_callbacks.py
import json
import logging

import dash
import requests  # type: ignore
from dash import ALL, Input, Output, State, callback


from app import common

@callback(
    Output("wave-select", "options"),
    # TODO: also populate initially selected value when options are working
    # default selected to last one in the list for now.
    Input("selected-project-store", "data")
)
def populate_waves_select(project_id, data):
    """
    Fetch project metadata for a selected project
    """
    if project_id and data:
        logger.info(f"----------------------starting with project selected store {project_id}")
        logger.info("Fetching waves")
        res = requests.get(
            f"{common.API_URL}/v0/projects/{project_id}/waves"
        )
        logger.info(f"---------------project waves response {res.text}")
    if res and res.text:
        options = [{'label':w['wave_name'], 'value': w['wave_id'] } for w in json.loads(res.text)]
        logger.info(f"---------------options {options}, first option {options[0]}")
        return options
    else:
        logger.info('----------------returning no update')
        return dash.no_update
```

my logs include entries that look like this to suggest it should be working...

```
{"timestamp": "2023-08-11 16:11:16,916", "levelname": "INFO", "source_code": "metadata_callbacks.py:44", "logger_name": "app.components.metadata.metadata_callbacks", "message": "----------------------starting with project selected store 230049b0-2c88-4b5e-947b-14bcfdef8666"}


{"timestamp": "2023-08-11 16:11:16,940", "levelname": "INFO", "source_code": "metadata_callbacks.py:50", "logger_name": "app.components.metadata.metadata_callbacks", "message": "---------------project waves response [{"wave_id":"617c9e8f-5cc1-422c-84d2-76e5106feb22","wave_name":"wave 1"},{"wave_id":"17305ab7-51fe-49ad-aa99-2fa9e3fa1333","wave_name":"wave 2"}]"}


{"timestamp": "2023-08-11 16:11:16,940", "levelname": "INFO", "source_code": "metadata_callbacks.py:53", "logger_name": "app.components.metadata.metadata_callbacks", "message": "---------------options [{'label': 'wave 1', 'value': '617c9e8f-5cc1-422c-84d2-76e5106feb22'}, {'label': 'wave 2', 'value': '17305ab7-51fe-49ad-aa99-2fa9e3fa1333'}], first option {'label': 'wave 1', 'value': '617c9e8f-5cc1-422c-84d2-76e5106feb22'}"}
```

see above code examples. logs look as expected but nothing actually populates to the dropdown options

Comment: Why does your callback function take two arguments, but the callback decorator just defines a single input argument?